# "Missing Authentication Token" Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I feel like this should be simple, but I've searched everywhere I can and haven't found my issue.  I'm trying to connect to AWS from Visual Studio using the .NET Toolkit for Visual Studio but I'm getting a "Request is missing Authentication Token" error (below):

[image]

I have all of the authentication information filled out:

[image]

Any ideas on what the issue is or where I can begin to troubleshoot?

Comment: That's an odd error to get in this situation. Is it possible you used session credentials in the Edit Account dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our company was blocking access somehow.  When we took the computer outside of the company firewall it ended up working just fine.  They ended up opening up a few ports for us and then it worked fine within the firewall.

Comment: This should be inserted as a comment, not an answer.